# Subsequently Draw Multiple Flot Charts

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I'm drawing multiple flot charts like so:

```
            $.plot('#pieForm', formPieData, optionsPie);
            $.plot('#pieVote', votePieData, optionsPie);
            $.plot('#lineUsers', usersLineData, optionsLineUsers);
            $.plot('#lineForm', formLineData, optionsLineForm);
            $.plot('#linePoll', pollLineData, optionsLinePoll);
```

This is proving to be inefficient with browser lag + crashes.

How would I go about drawing each graph subsequently after each one has finished drawing instead of all at once ?

Comment: To my knowledge, this would draw each plot in sequence and **not** all at once.  Also, I routinely draw a dozen or more graphs like this and see barely any lag and **no** crashes?  So, what sort of errors are you getting?  Do you have your `$.plot` calls in a `.ready()` (http://api.jquery.com/ready/)?

Comment: What browser are you testing on, and what version of Flot are you using?  How large are your datasets?  What's the size of your placeholders?